# How to specify ingredients in Schema.org (other than recipes or drugs)?

Tags: semantic-web, microdata

I'd like to use [Schema.org](http://schema.org) for a series of product specs pages.

The products are cosmetics (shampoos, creams, etc.) and ideally an [INCI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Nomenclature_of_Cosmetic_Ingredients) declaration will be included for every product.

I'd like to use Schema.org in the declaration, but I cannot find a suitable category in Schema.org. *Ingredients* is meant for cooking recipes, and *ActiveIngredient* for (medical) drugs and dietary supplements.

Did I overlook some part of the tree? Any ideas for a workaround? Or am I trying to do something out of scope?

Comment: Why do you want to use schema for this?   Schema is useful when you know that somebody wants to scrape this data off your website.   You agree to use the schema because you want to allow them to do so and you want to make it easy.   Finding some schema to fit your data in the hopes that somebody will stumble across it and find it useful makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `product` schema class for each product, and then specify the INCI's using an additional (custom) property for each one, for example if your shampoo had Shea Butter and Water as ingredients (clearly I'm no expert on cosmetics!):

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
  <img itemprop="image" src="shampoo123.jpg" alt="" />
  <span itemprop="name">Shampoo Product Name</span>
  <div itemprop="additionalProperty" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PropertyValue">
      <span itemprop="name">Ingredient</span>:
      <span itemprop="value">Butyrospermum Parkii (Shea Butter)</span>
      <meta itemprop="identifier" content="Butyrospermum Parkii (Shea Butter)"/>
      <meta itemprop="description" content="Shea Butter"/>
      <meta itemprop="propertyID" content="INCI"/>
  </div>
  <div itemprop="additionalProperty" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PropertyValue">
      <span itemprop="name">Ingredient</span>:
      <span itemprop="value">Aqua (Water)</span>
      <meta itemprop="identifier" content="Aqua (Water)"/>
      <meta itemprop="description" content="Water"/>
      <meta itemprop="propertyID" content="INCI"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Beyond this if you wanted a specific schema for your cosmetic products you could:

(a) [create your own schema extension](http://schema.org/docs/extension.html) for your requirements, or

(b) [propose and contribute](http://schema.org/docs/howwework.html) a new descendant of `Product` such as `CosmeticProduct`

Answer (score 0):

By the way, an interesting observation. HTML markup is the best option.
Schema.org is a recommendation for the search engine so that Google can better understand what kind of content you have on the page. But if your code is clean, and you use lists or a table, then Google will easily pull it into a snippet.
I made a test site with recipes. no micromarking at all,
just good and correct HTML code. As a result, my snippets were exactly the same as the snippets that have micro-markup.

Answer (score -2):

GoogleWebmasterTools has a tool about that, please see the image and ask another question if you need help:
[image: markup]

Comment: Can you explain how this tool helps in  more detail?

Comment: It provides you with the code that you need to add to your page for the choosed markup.

Comment: As far as I have seen, this tool is not useful for the type of data in question.

Comment: If one cannot find the type of content, that wants to highlight, then this content should not be highlighted.